# PIL Image.py not loading after MacOs update 10.13.4

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

After I updated my Mac, PIL image is no longer working.

This was the error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 56, in <module> from . import _imaging as core ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trying, my fix was swithing back from libjpeg 9c to 9b:

```
brew switch libjpeg 9b
```

I hope my fix will spare you some time and I would be happy to hear a better way to fix this than a brutal downgrade.